# remove navmesh component after move

Tags: unity-game-engine

I make a class for move an game object look like this :

```c#
public class Navmesh_move : MonoBehaviour {
    private NavMeshAgent _thismove;
    Transform test;
    //Vector3 destenation_Pos;  
    Vector3 destenation_Position,vector3test;
    // Use this for initialization
    public void move(float x,float y,float z)
    {

        //this.transform.Rotate (0, 0, 180);

        _thismove =this.gameObject.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        destenation_Position = new Vector3(x,y,z);
        _thismove.SetDestination(destenation_Position);
        NavMeshAgent tempnavmesh = new NavMeshAgent ();
        tempnavmesh =this.gameObject.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent> ();
        tempnavmesh.enabled = false;
        //this.transform.position=destenation_Position;

    }
```

}

Then I attributed this to an Object Game.

but before add `tempnavmesh.enabled = false;`  my game object move correct.but after add that line i get `"SetDestination" can only be called on an active agent that has been placed on a NavMesh.` error and my game object doesn/t to move.

how to remove `navmeshAgent` component after move a game object???

Comment: Instead of removing you could stop Calling the move Method. - Are you sure you only want to move that object a single time? If that is really what you want to do - use Destroy(this);

Comment: @TobiasTheel .....hi my dear friend....no in runtime To an unknown number i need to add navmeshAgent commponent to To different objects and remove its component after move.........It's not clear how many times these attributes are to be attributed to these objects........this is very Dynamiclly

Comment: I guess this is not the best approach. continuosly allocating(adding) & destroying(removing) is gonna impact your performance. You should really think of a solution, where you reuse the components instead of removing and adding them afterwards

Answer (score 0):

i have found a solution  for my problem.
look like this:

```c#
public void move(float x,float y,float z)
{

    //this.transform.Rotate (0, 0, 180);

    _thismove =this.gameObject.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    destenation_Position = new Vector3(x,y,z);
    _thismove.SetDestination(destenation_Position);
    Invoke ("disablenavmeshagent", 2);      
}

//-------------------------------------
void disablenavmeshagent()
{
    NavMeshAgent tempnavmesh = new NavMeshAgent ();
    tempnavmesh =this.gameObject.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent> ();
    tempnavmesh.enabled = false;
}
```